# Handlebars on Cart.html

Tags: handlebars.js, product, cart, bigcommerce, cornerstone

Is there any way to access a product with variations/options individual weight?
Currently have an old script pulling a basic product (no variations/options) through custom fields. Now I have products with variations all with different weights, so the custom fields solution no longer works...

Ideally I want to pull the product options weight to add to my script to total the cart's weight. Tried ?debug=context at the end of a localhost URL and could  not find product option weight to be available on the cart page- are there other options to work around this??

I am on BigCommerce Cornerstone theme

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand by reading your post, the best way to accomplish your goal will be with the storefront GraphQL API. Using GraphQL you can query each product in the cart and include the variant data with the weight. This will allow you to get the weight for all of the variants in the order and add them up to get the total.

I'd definitely suggest checking out the [BigCommerce GraphQL Documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/graphql/graphql-storefront-api-overview) for more information, as well as the [Code Examples](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/graphql/graphql-storefront-api-samples).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jordan! Do you know if there is any extra info/tutorials on how to implement the GraphQL API? I have not used an API in my store's code, not sure how to start working with it. Appreciate it!

Comment: @alexispsc The [BigCommerce GraphQL Overview](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/graphql/graphql-storefront-api-overview) is going to be the best source of information for this. It'll go over how to fetch GraphQL data using JavaScript fetch on the storefront which is exactly what you'll want to do on the cart page. I'd suggest reading over the overview carefully, but the most important part for you will be the **Querying within a BigCommerce storefront** section. :-)